# How can lock be List itself when iterating a SynchronizedList?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

Please see the following code:

```
    List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
    // ...
    synchronized (list) {
        Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
        while (i.hasNext())
            foo(i.next());
    }
```

I know caller should synchronize when iterating a synchronied list, but I cannot understand why using "list" as lock. Inner SynchronizedList class, the private member mutex is the lock. so if caller using "list" as lock, locks are different between caller and inner. I think this truth makes synchronization no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the code of Collections.synchronizedList. Then you will find the implementation of  synchronizedList uses the "this" to lock when add or remove method. Here you lock "list" to prevent from invoking the "add" or "remove" methods.

Comment: I see the code of Collections.synchronizedList, and find the lock is "mutex" not "this". So I'm confused...

Comment: You can see the code here, "mutex=this"(SynchronizedList is a subclass of SynchronizedCollection, in the construct method of SynchronizedCollection): http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#1602

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I'm so careless. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because to make the iteration atomic and thread safe, you need to use the same lock as the synchronizedList, which happens to be [the list itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29). In the code, the default constructor uses this as a mutex:

```
SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {

    if (c==null)

        throw new NullPointerException();

    this.c = c;

    mutex = this; // <=== here

}
```

Comment: Thank you also. I know the private member "mutex" is just "this", and I'm clear now.